# Как правильно наследовать класс?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, clion

Создаю класс Stack, который наследует LinkedList, но выдает ошибку еще при компиляции, подскажите, в чем проблема.

Ошибка:

> "D:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\cmake-build-debug --target StudyProj --
>   -j 2 Scanning dependencies of target StudyProj [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj In file included from
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\main.cpp:2:0:
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\Stack.h:8:35: error: expected
>   class-name before '{' token  class Stack : protected LinkedList{
>                                      ^ D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\Stack.h: In instantiation of 'void
>   Stack::push(T) [with T = int]':
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\main.cpp:6:17:   required from here
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\Stack.h:43:11: error: 'class
>   Stack' has no member named 'prepend'
>        this->prepend(data);
>        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~ D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\Stack.h: In instantiation of 'T Stack::pop() [with T = int]':
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\main.cpp:12:23:   required from here
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\Stack.h:49:11: error: 'class
>   Stack' has no member named 'remove'
>        this->remove(res);
>        ~~~~~~^~~~~~ CMakeFiles\StudyProj.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error
>   1 mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all] Error 2
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all' failed CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe
>   for target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule' failed Makefile:117: recipe
>   for target 'StudyProj' failed mingw32-make.exe[1]: 
>   **[CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe: ***
>   [StudyProj] Error 2

LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    template<class T>
    class LinkedList {
    private:
        struct node {
            T data;
            node *next;
        } *head;
    public:
        LinkedList();

        ~LinkedList();

        void append(T data);

        void prepend(T data);

        void remove(T data);

        void clear();

        void output();
    };

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    head=NULL;
};
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    node *p, *q;
    p = head;
    if(p==NULL) return;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }
}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::prepend(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    p = this->head;
    q = new node;
    q->data = data;
    q->next = p;
    this->head = q;
}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head == NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        if(p->data == data){
            q->next = p->next;
            delete p;
            return;
        }
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        if(q != head){
            head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        p = q;
    }
}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    p = head;
    while(p->next!=NULL)
        p = p->next;
    q = new node;
    q->data = data;
    q->next = NULL;
    p->next = q;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::output() {
    if(this->head == NULL){
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    node *p;
    p = this->head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->data << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}
```

Stack.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

template<class T>
class Stack : protected LinkedList{
private:
    struct node {
        T data;
        node *next;
    } *top;
    node *down;
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void push(T);
    T pop();
    T peek();
    void output();
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack() {
    top = down = NULL;
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    node *p, *q;
    p = top;
    if(p==NULL) return;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }
};

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data){
    this->prepend(data);
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(){
    T res = this->top->data;
    this->remove(res);
    return res;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::peek(){
    return this->top->data;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::output(){
    this->output();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "Stack.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);

    cout << stack.pop();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `LinkedList` шаблонный, он по сути создается только в момент использования с каким-то типом. Поэтому наследование должно выглядеть

```
template<class T>
class Stack : protected LinkedList<T> {
    // something
};
```

Answer (score 4):

У вас в коде нет класса `LinkedList`. У вас в коде есть *шаблон* класса `LinkedList` с одним параметром. Использовать этот шаблон класса там, где требуется именно класс, можно только при условии указания аргументов шаблона. У вас же написано

```
template<class T>
class Stack : protected LinkedList {
```

Это не является корректным объявлением, ибо аргументы шаблона `LinkedList` не указаны. Что вы имели в виду под этим `LinkedList`? Скорее всего `LinkedList<T>`? Тогда так и пишите.

Отдельное недоумение вызывает то, что вы вдруг зачем-то явно взялись реализовывать удаление элементов в деструкторе `Stack<T>::~Stack()`, при том что деструктор `LinkedList` и так сам это делает. Непонятно также, почему деструктор `LinkedList` не пользуется собственным методом `clear()`, а вместо этого выписывает удаление с нуля. (Хотя надо признать, что в методе `clear` написана какая-то белиберда.)

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет!
(Я только начинаю С++ учить, так что, да, делаю много ошибок, пытаюсь учиться на них же)